# POSTGRESQL : Old owner present on new installation

Tags: postgresql

I want to flush this DB so that the old owner doesn't exist anymore and I want to be the superuser.

I am using an ex-colleagues laptop ( mac )

PostgreSQL ( psql ) was installed via Homebrew ( 9.6 ) which I have removed as I required ( 9.5 ).

A few "perhaps" issues I've noticed:
psql9.5 is now installed and when I attempt to login I receive the following *FATAL:  role "MY NAME" does not exist*

eventually login and when I "\l" I see the following:

```
DB_NAME-> \l
                                        List of databases
   Name    |    Owner     | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |       Access privileges
-----------+--------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------
 DB_NAME   | DB_NAME      | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 |
 postgres  | EX COLLEAGUE | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 |
 template0 | EX COLLEAGUE | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/EX COLLEAGUE              +
           |              |          |             |             | EX COLLEAGUE=CTc/EX COLLEAGUE
 template1 | EX COLLEAGUE | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/EX COLLEAGUE              +
           |              |          |             |             | EX COLLEAGUE=CTc/EX COLLEAGUE
```

when I run:

```
DB_NAME=> \du
                                     List of roles
  Role name   |                         Attributes                         | Member of
--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 DB_NAME      | Create DB                                                  | {}
 EX COLLEAGUE | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

I can't create new Roles.

I might be over-exaggerating the severity of this - but I have no idea what to do.

I have looked at old resources and maybe I was searching incorrectly but I found no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - had to re-install my Mac OS but was hoping for a less time consuming option